# Rock, paper, scissors valid input check

Tags: if-statement, input, printing, while-loop

I'm trying to make a rock, paper, scissors game in python, and I'm trying to trying to write a piece of code that checks if the input is valid.

```
if choice_lower != "rock" or choice_lower != "paper" or choice_lower != "scissors":
    print("invalid input")
```

The game works fine, however when I try to run it with this input check implemented, even if I input the correct input, the program still prints "invalid input". Any tips with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

That's because when you enter "rock", you met the condition of `choice_lower != "paper"` and `choice_lower != "scissors"`, thus printing the invalid input.

A fix would be to change all the `or` to `and`.

```
if choice_lower != "rock" and choice_lower != "paper" and choice_lower != "scissors":
    print("invalid input")
```